# List View Limitations for sub folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise we h ave a default list view of 10,000 documents.  If I create a Parent Folder Called Parent and store nothing in the Parent, but 9,000 documents in a sub folder (underneath Parent) called Child 1 and  9,000 documents in a sub folder called Child 2 would all 9,000 documents be available to view when I click on Child 1 ?  Would all 9,000 documents be available to view when I click on Child 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not it won't be if you are have default list item threshold value set to 5000 and when you are viewing child 1 view, it will not return data because you have 9000 documents in this folder. Same case goes for child 2 folder.

But Yes..it would be available...provided your  item view threshold is set to greater than 9000. This settings you are override for on premises.

Hope this helps..Happy coding..!!!

Answer (score 0):

The list view threshold also applies to the sub folders. The default value of List View Threshold is 5000 and 20000 for auditors and administrators.

So it depends on what permissions do you have.

Answer (score 0):

No, you wont be able to view the files in the subfolders due to threshold limit. To over come that you should use sorting and grouping feature of the list views in addition to applying filters to create the views as per the requirements.